# System.Drawing Fast Enough For 2D Game Programming?

Tags: c#, graphics, .net-4.0, gdi+, system.drawing

Say I am making a 2D Tile Based game in C# using System.Drawing for graphics.

**OOP Layer for GDI?**

*The System.Drawing namespace provides access to GDI+ basic graphics functionality.* ~ MSDN

Back when I was starting out Graphics & Game programming in C, a lot of books such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672323699) one taught me that a software-rendered API like GDI was not efficient enough for Double-Buffered 2D games running at a decent FPS. So does Microsoft .NET's System.Drawing implementation fall into the same category? Does it use GDI & GDI+ under the hood, or can it use a different, faster backend?

**How Much FPS Can I Hope For?**

Even if System.Drawing can only use GDI, is it impossible to make a game run at a decent Frame rate, say 50-60 frames per second, with GDI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a question of it being fast enough as it is it being suitable for the task you want to perform. In all honesty, it's quite easy to implement basic functionality to do the drawing you require using for instance XNA, and you get so much for free. There is simply no reason to go into `System.Drawing` for making games.

The book you linked in quite ancient, while it contains a few algorithms that never goes out of style most of it is really outdated.

As to how much FPS you can get from System.Drawing, you can probably get enough FPS from it from a simple tile based game. It's going to work if you do it that way, but it will hinder you from making real progress later on - especially as the threshold for making games using XNA is so low these days.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite unguessable what kind of FPS you'll get, it entirely depends on how intricate your scenes are.  The biggest restriction in GDI/+ rendering is that bitmaps are stored in main memory, not video adapter memory.  So most anything you draw has to be copied from RAM to the video adapter's frame buffer.  Sure, that's relatively slow but unavoidable as long as you don't adopt an API that can manage memory on the video adapter.  There are few reasons left to avoid this kind of API, there isn't any hardware left that doesn't support DirectX.

The equivalent of page flipping is easy to get, just set the form's or control's DoubleBuffered property to true.  Anything you draw goes into a back-buffer first, that buffer is blitted to the video adapter after the Paint event completes.  The only thing you won't get is synchronization with the adapter's vertical refresh interval so tearing is pretty unavoidable.  How noticeable that will be depends a great deal on how quickly you move objects in the scene.

The only other detail is the pixel format of any bitmaps you draw.  Sprites, textures, that sort of thing.  The format you pick is very important.  On current hardware, Format32bppPArgb is ten times faster than any of the other ones.  If you do any rescaling on the bitmaps then the Graphics.InterpolationMode property is important for speed.  The good ones are expensive.  You can rescale them in a worker thread as long as you make sure that only one thread ever accesses the bitmap at the same time.

But be sure to have a look at DirectX (SlimDX for example) and XNA.  Hard to beat for convenience, just a lot less work to do.

Comment: SlimDX (http://slimdx.org) is a very good recommendation as a managed Direct2D/Direct3D wrapper (plus a lot of other features), and I'd recommend it over XNA or MDX if you're targetting Windows.  If you think you'll be going to other platforms, you might want to invest in OpenGL.  The OpenTK (http://opentk.com) bindings for .NET are also quite complete.